# Custom layout for each row in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, custom-adapter

I am trying to get a button to work in a ListView Row. I been Reading about Custom Adapter but can't get it to work. Basically what i have a List_item class that have 4 TextView and 1 button which fieds a ListView in another class. one of the textViews has id/Name. so what i want is when i press the button on that row. it will get that Value of TextView "name" and add it to a ArrayList and if i press another button on different row it will add the Value of "name" to the same arraylist. so basically will add all the ones that i pressed on the button to an ArrayList. is that possible??.

JUST TO ADD. the textView Are being feed in by my database ..thanks upfront for any replies.

List_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my menu.xml has

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="697dp" >
</ListView>
```

now i want to get Values of TextView " name " when i press the button on its row.

that is how i used to fill my listView before i add the button and it was working fine

```
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter (getCategoryItems.this,itemsList,R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ TAG_ID, TAG_NAME,TAG_PRICE, TAG_DESCRIPTION},new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.price, R.id.description});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

but now after i added the button it doesn't get any values so i reaserched and i found that i have to change my sampleAdapter to a custom Adapter. and add the button inside getView() but i can't get that hang of it.

my button OnClickListener

```
Button order = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.order);
order.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        String name = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        Log.d("Selected : ", name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post a minimal amount of code to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: I added the background method which should happen before i do a listAdapter in the postexceute().

Comment: Since your question has nothing to do with JSON, I suggest that you write a simpler example with some hard-coded data.

Comment: At a glance that looks much better. I'll take a closer look a little later and see what I can do to help.

Comment: It looks like the next step is to add an OnClickListener to each of your Buttons. What have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: yeah first i tried to add OnClickListener for my buttons but it i didn't work as i needed the postion of row so it can get the information. then i tried to add my button and OnClickListener into my onItemClick of the list view, it works fine only if i selected the item first then pressed the button after. but if i pressed the button straight with out selecting the item it does nothing. So still means it wants the position from the view.

Comment: When you use SimpleAdapter? Do the buttons appear correctly in your ListView?

Comment: yeah everything is there and in the right place.

Comment: Please add the OnClickListener to your original question. It doesn't format well in a comment. Also, where do you put the code that sets up the OnClickListener?

Comment: done . sorry about that

Comment: i tried to add OnClickListener for my buttons in my OnCreate but it i didn't work as i needed the postion of row so it can get the information. then i tried to add my button and OnClickListener into my onItemClick of the list view, it works fine only if i selected the item first then pressed the button after. but if i pressed the button straight with out selecting the item it does nothing. So still means it wants the position from the view

Comment: Does your Activity class extend ListActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom adapter class for your `ListView`. Since you are getting data from a database, I suggest that you extend `CursorAdapter` and override `newView()` and `bindView()`. From my experience, how to do this correctly is poorly documented, so I'll try to give some pointers here.

In `newView()`, you need to use a `LayoutInflator` which is provided to you by calling `getLayoutInflator()` on your `ListActivity`. After you call `inflate()` on this `LayoutInflator`, you can then get the Button for that specific row and set its `OnClickListener`.

In `bindView()`, you do just about all the same things, except that you don't need to inflate a new view since Android is requesting that you reuse an existing `View` object. You might want to create some extra methods in order to reduce the amount of repeated code.

I hope this helps even though it is explained in English rather than with a code example.

Comment: thanks alot. i will work my way through it with that information you provided me.

Comment: @MoAdel You might look at extending `SimpleCursorAdapter` rather than just `CursorAdapter`. You might be able to take advantage of it to populate the `TextView` for you so you don't have to do it manually.